# How to add mouse hover properties to pie drawn on a node in d3?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, hover

I'm working with a visualization where some of the nodes in the network have pie charts on them with varying radius and varying number of slices based on some parameters. This is what the visualization looks like in the default state:

[image: snapshot of the visualization]

When I hover on a chosen node, only its connections are prominent and the rest fades away (decreases in opacity). While this works perfectly with nodes, I'm unable to apply the same settings to my pie-chart arcs. How do I fade away the lines within the pie-charts of the other nodes as well while keeping those on the currently active node untouched?

This image shows the hover effect and the problem with the pie-charts:

[image: snapshot of hover effect on visualization]

As you can see, the lines within the pie do not fade away while the nodes does.
Here's the code snippet I'm currently working with.

Creating the nodes and the pie slices within them (based on some internal selection criteria):

```
var outer = d3.select("#forcedLayoutGraph")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("pointer-events", "all");

    var vis = outer
        .append('svg:g')
        .call(zoom);

    vis.append('svg:rect')
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h)
        .attr('fill', 'white');

    var n = nodes.length;

    var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
        .data(links).enter()
        .append("svg:line")
        .attr("class", "link").style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

    var colorCategory = {"1": "black", "2": "blue", "3": "red"};            // 1=root 2=blog 3=org
    var shapeCategory = {"1": "diamond", "2": "cross", "3": "circle"};      // 1=root 2=blog 3=org
    var colorDirectChild = {"1": "black", "2": "#8E44AD", "3": "#F1C40F"};      // 1=root 2=direct child of root 3=not direct child

    var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("text")
        .text("");

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r",  10)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return colorDirectChild[d.isDirectChild]; });

var r = 6;
        var x = 2;
            //fill=d3.scale.category(20);

        var donut = d3.layout.pie();
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0).outerRadius(function(d) {
                        if(this.parentNode.parentNode.__data__.category == 3)
                            if(this.parentNode.parentNode.__data__.parentcount < 10)
                                value = 10; //divide by a factor x, also remove (+r)
                            else
                                value = (this.parentNode.parentNode.__data__.parentcount)/x + r;
                        else
                            value = 0;
                        return value;
                  });

        var arcs = node.selectAll("g.arc")
                       .data(function(d, i) {
                            var c=0; var groups = [];
                            for(c=0; c<d.parentcount; c++) {
                                groups.push(1.0/d.parentcount);
                            }
                            return donut(groups);
                        })
                        .enter().append("svg:g") 
                        .attr("class", "arc");

        arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", "#F1C40F")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", "1.25px")
            .attr("d", arc);
```

Here's the code for manipulating the hover effect on the nodes:

```
node.on("mouseover", function(d){
       node.classed("node-active", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? true : false;
            this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
            return thisOpacity;
        });

        node.classed("node-inactive", function(o) {
            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? false : true;
            this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
            return thisOpacity;
        });

        link.classed("link-active", function(o) {
            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? true : false;
        });



        var nodeText, nodeParentCnt; 
        d3.select(this).classed("node-inactive", false);
        d3.select(this).classed("node-active", true);

        d3.select("g.arc").attr("stroke-width","0.25px");
        d3.select(this).select("g.arc").attr("stroke-wdith","1.25px");

        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("r", 20);
        d3.select(this).select("text")
            .attr("dx", 12)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { nodeText = d.label; nodeParentCnt = d.parentcount; return d.label; });
        d3.select("#nodeLabel").text(nodeText)
        d3.select(this).select("circle")
            .on("click", function(d){
                var win = window.open(d.label, '_blank');
                win.focus();
            });
        //console.log(nodeText);
        document.getElementById('nodeLabel').innerHTML = "URL: "+nodeText + "<br />" + "No. of Linking URLs: " + nodeParentCnt;
    })

    .on("mouseout", function(d){
        node.classed("node-active", false);
        link.classed("link-active", false); 
        node.classed("node-inactive", false);   

        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr("r", 10);
        d3.select(this).select("text")
            .text("");
        document.getElementById('nodeLabel').innerHTML = "Hover on a node!";
    });
```

These are the CSS properties associated with the node and link classes:

```
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 0.2px;
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.node-active{
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.node-inactive{
  fill-opacity: 0.2;
}

.link {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke-opacity: 0.2;
}

.link-active {
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}
```

I hope this code sample helps to give an idea of what I'm working with. How can I apply similar effects to the pie? Does it have to be a separate code block for mouse events or does it go within the code for the nodes? I'm still figuring my way out in D3.

Comment: It looks like you need to set `stroke-opacity` for `.node-inactive` as well.

Comment: Yep! That did the trick. I can't believe I didn't notice that, thanks a lot! Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: can I also draw your attention to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056786/how-to-arrange-several-hundred-nodes-in-symmetrical-concentric-circles-based-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pie charts are rendered using `path` elements, which aren't affected by `fill-opacity` that you're setting for the `.node-inactive` class. You also need to set `stroke-opacity` to see an effect.