# How to arrange several hundred nodes in symmetrical concentric circles based on selection criteria in D3 forced layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm pretty new to D3 and working with a force direction layout which currently has about a 1000 nodes. The visualization as of now looks as shown below:

[image]

In the above network, the red node in the center of the page is the root node, solid yellow nodes are level 1 nodes and yellow nodes with pie-slices in them are level 2 nodes. I have a property attached to each node, 'category' where

```
category = 1: root node
category = 2: level 1 node
category = 3: level 2 node
```

I'm unable to manipulate the charge/link-distance/friction in a way that the root node is in the center, level 1 nodes are neatly arranged around the root node and level 2 nodes are arranged in the outermost circle. This is the code snippet that I'm currently working with that creates and adjusts the force:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([-1, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function(d) { return d; })
        .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("dragend", dragended);
    
    var force = d3.layout.force()       // charge is for inter-node repel, link distance is node-node distance
        .charge(function(d){ //originally charge was just -150 and there was no function
        var charge = -150;
        if (d.index === 0) 
            charge = 20 * charge;
        return charge;})
        .gravity(-0.01)     
        .linkDistance(function(d){ //originally charge was just 150 and there was no function
        var linkDist = 150;
        if (d.category == 2) 
            linkDist = 2 * linkDist;
        else if(d.category == 3)
            linkDist = 4 * linkDist;
        return linkDist;})
        //.linkStrength(0.2)
        .friction(0.9)
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .size([w, h])
        .start();
```

I hope this is enough for me to convey the problem. In the current code, I tried playing with charge and link-distance but it isn't working. I can further code if needed. How can I achieve the desired layout using the right d3 and force-layout properties?

Edit: I'm currently using a tick function that looks like the following (not sure if this must be tweaked to manually position the nodes):

```
force.on("tick", function() {
        nodes[0].x = w / 2;
        nodes[0].y = h / 2;
        
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    
        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    });
```

Comment: Instead of trying to manipulate the force layout properties, it would be easier to just set the positions directly. Do that by creating a tick handler; in that handler, explicitly set the `x` and `y` properties of the root node to the center, etc.. The layout will then arrange the nodes subject to those constraints.

Comment: But how do I determine the exact coordinates for a thousand nodes? I mean, it's sure easy to just set the root in the center (w/2, h/2) but what sort of an algorithms would set the exact position coordinates for the other nodes?

Comment: Don't set the exact position of the secondary nodes. Let the layout run, but within the tick handler adjust the position to suit your requirements. For example, if you want a secondary node to be a fixed distance from the center, use the angle that the layout calculates but adjust the radius.

Comment: That makes more sense to me now. Could you just add a very basic code with a few nodes to illustrate how I can do this? That would be a great help!

Comment: @StephenThomas I've added some code indicating a tick function I'm already using. Not sure if this helps but just take a look.